# How to get rid of OPEN_CHILDREN_LIMIT_EXCEEDED in AWS SWF test

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am getting the following error when I tried to run the workflow.Start()

```
Configuration workflowInput = ConfigurationBuilder.getEmpty();
RemoteFilesFetchWorkflowClient workflowClient = workflowFactory.getClient();

Promise<Void> result = workflowClient.start(workflowInput);
```

> com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.StartChildWorkflowFailedException: OPEN_CHILDREN_LIMIT_EXCEEDED for workflowExecution="{WorkflowId: c6948b63-4134-4b67-b69a-8ab7160b5d9a,RunId: 954ed658-b7aa-4598-a215-c2b35db298f0}" of workflowType={Name: RemoteFilesFetchWorkflow.start,Version: 1.0}

I am unable to find the cause for this and resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-limits.html) the default limit for the open workflow executions is 100k per domain. This includes child workflow executions. Are you trying to execute more than 100k simultaneously? If your use case requires this then submit [Amazon SWF Limit Increase Form](http://www.amazon.com/gp/html-forms-controller/AmazonSWF_Limit_Increase_Form) to get your limit increased.

**Edit:** For the unit test this exception is thrown by the [following line of code](https://github.com/aws/aws-swf-flow-library/blob/e0c6d1bbdddb07b06e8338a5b2aa6ba9cc7de771/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/test/TestGenericWorkflowClient.java#L271). It looks like the actual error is linked to the exception as the cause. Look at the complete stack trace to see the original exception.

Comment: No. I am writing the above code in a junit test case. When I run my actual code, the work flow get registered in AWS.

Comment: Updated the answer